# Display array in the table with dynamic number of columns

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

Say I got an array from the server.

```
  var arr = [
            { ID: "001", Name: "a00",  isChecked: "true" },
            { ID: "002", Name: "b00",  isChecked: "true" }, 
            { ID: "003", Name: "c00",  isChecked: "true" },
            { ID: "004", Name: "d00",  isChecked: "true" },
            { ID: "005", Name: "e00",  isChecked: "true" },
            { ID: "006", Name: "f00",  isChecked: "true" }, 
            { ID: "007", Name: "g00",  isChecked: "true" },
            { ID: "008", Name: "h00",  isChecked: "true" }, 
            { ID: "009", Name: "i00",  isChecked: "true" },
            { ID: "010", Name: "j00",  isChecked: "true" }, 
            { ID: "011", Name: "k00",  isChecked: "true" },
            { ID: "012", Name: "l00",  isChecked: "true" },
            { ID: "013", Name: "m00",  isChecked: "true" },
            { ID: "014", Name: "n00",  isChecked: "true" }, 
            { ID: "015", Name: "o00",  isChecked: "true" },
            { ID: "016", Name: "p00",  isChecked: "true" }, 
             // ....many many rows

        ]
```

Now I want to display it in a table with a certain number of columns. For example, if I want to display it in 4 columns. Then I use

```
 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let group of arr">
      <td>{{group.name}}</td>
      <td>{{group.name}}</td>
      <td>{{group.name}}</td>
      <td>{{group.name}}</td>
   </tr>
```

The expected result likes

```
a00 | b00 | c00 | d00
e00 | f00 | g00 | h00
.....
```

If I chose 7 columns. Then the code is:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let group of arr">
        <td>{{group.name}}</td>
        <td>{{group.name}}</td>
        <td>{{group.name}}</td>
        <td>{{group.name}}</td>
        <td>{{group.name}}</td>
        <td>{{group.name}}</td>
        <td>{{group.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

The expected result likes:

```
a00 | b00 | c00 | d00 | e00 | f00 | g00
....
```

However I don't know if it is 4 or 7, the chunk size is given by a variable `size`. So how to do it?

Comment: @NicholasK, I did it. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do so using:

1. Convert the array to a 2D array depending on the size variable.
2. Now iterate over this array in the template.

.ts

```
newArr = []
size = 2;    // change this as per your requirement

ngOnInit() {
  while (this.arr.length) { 
    this.newArr.push(this.arr.splice(0, this.size)); // create 2D array
  }
}
```

.html

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let outer of newArr">
            <td *ngFor="let group of outer">{{group.Name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/2d-array-13)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `size` variable you can create an array with the length of size and use another `*ngFor` with that array to render the columns.

Example

#### Component

```
class MyComponent extend OnInit {
   size = 4;
   sizeArray = [];

   ngOnInit() {
     this.sizeArray = new Array(this.size)
   }
}
```

#### Template

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let group of arr">
    <td *ngFor="let index of sizeArray">
      {{group.name}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```